# Using Ant in Mercurial

Tags: ant, mercurial, build

I am trying to run an Ant build on a Mercurial repository and I am having some trouble.  The Ant task can't seem to find the `build.xml` file.  When I look through the Hg repo, I can find my file at:

```
myrepo/.hg/store/data/build
```

but inside here, the `build.xml` file is named `build.xml.i` and I think this may be confusing Ant, although I'm not sure.

What is the best way to run an Ant script against a Mercurial repository?  Or am I doing this completely wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the build directory isn't ignored? (`.hgignore`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the 'working directory' with the version of build.xml you want.  This is generally the latest, so you can:

```
$ cd hgrepo
$ hg update
$ ant build
```

Where `hgrepo` is the Mercurial repository.

Comment: Well, I should have clarified, I am trying to run on a build.xml file in a remote repository.  So, in my local repository, I can find the file easily.  But, my remote is on a Linux server on the network.  So when I go to that server and look up the repository, I can't find the file there.

Comment: What I've actually done is run hg archive on the remote repository.  I was then able to get at my file.  However, this just doesn't seem right.  Is there a better way?

Comment: If the remote repo is your central repo then you don't want to run stuff from there; it's much better to create a temporary working directory by cloning the repo, doing your thing and then deleting the repo.  In fact our central repos aren't accessible from anything other than Apache.

Comment: `hg archive` to another location and building there is just fine.  `hg archive` inside the repo itself (building a working copy using `hg archive`) would be an inferior way to do `hg update` or `hg revert`.  Were I you I'd create a clone that's updated to tip and build in there.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to run a build inside the repository (myrepo/.hg/store/data/build). That, and may other things will fail unless you use a *work directory*. To get a work directory, tell HG to clone the repository.

In other words, you should treat HG repositories as obscure databases only to be manipulated through HG commands. The same applies to any other VC/SCM system (try taking a look inside a SVN repository).

Comment: So, I'm guessing my above method of using hg archive is not the preferred approach?  I have a working directory on my local, but running the build.xml file performs a build to a local server (we are using a CMS with a CMS server).

Comment: @sma It's not "not preferred", it is forbidden. You should not know or care about what goes into the HG repositories as long as the updates, commits, pushes, and pulls work.

Comment: Thank you.  I did some reading last night in conjunction with these comments.  I think I better understand the concept of working directory now.  Thank you all for the help.